# Setting up data adapter: can’t connect data to model

Tags: sqlite, dataset, autodesk-forge

After I adapted my SQL dataset according to my model, the sensor list just disappeared from localhost, and the SQL command is not generating the expected data (a table from sample.db). Default dataset was Hyperion but I changed it to my dataset sensors.

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/advanced_topics/sqlite_adapter/

[image: localhost]

[image]

What is the problem? What kind of table is expected to come from the SQL database?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the Data Viz Extension tutorial is a work-in-progress.

Before these tutorials are finished, I'd suggest that you take a look at a sample app that I've been working on: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-iot-extensions-demo. It's also using the Data Visualization Extensions but it aims to be simpler and easier to reuse. By default, the IoT sensors, channels, and samples are defined in a simple JSON, but I've put together a separate code branch ([sample/sqlite](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-iot-extensions-demo/tree/sample/sqlite)) where the IoT data is fetched from a sample sqlite database.