# Data Visualization Extension: Hyperion Data Adaptor (Type Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach'))

Tags: sql, visualization, adapter, autodesk-forge, hyperion

in process of Data Visualization Extension, I made my dataset for sensors and adapted it to my Revit model. Also I used (Setting Up a SQLite Data Adapter).

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/advanced_topics/sqlite_adapter/

[image: Setting Up a SQLite Data Adapter]

Unfortunately, after loading the model in localhost:9000, there is no sensor list and data. this error is on the console.
**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')**

[image: Error]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Link to related answer: [Setting Up an SQLite Data Adapter for Data Visualization Extension: I can’t connect my SQL data to model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74202588/setting-up-an-sqlite-data-adapter-for-data-visualization-extension-i-can-t-conn/74274906#74274906).

> Please note that the Data Viz Extension tutorial is a work-in-progress. Before these tutorials are finished, I'd suggest that you take a look at a sample app that I've been working on: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-iot-extensions-demo. It's also using the Data Visualization Extensions but it aims to be simpler and easier to reuse. By default, the IoT sensors, channels, and samples are defined in a simple JSON, but I've put together a separate code branch ([sample/sqlite](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-iot-extensions-demo/tree/sample/sqlite)) where the IoT data is fetched from a sample sqlite database.

Comment: Would you please guide me, how I can add my own extensions to this package (forge-iot-extensions-demo)?

Comment: Extensions are basically JavaScript classes derived from `Autodesk.Viewing.Extension` that you load into the viewer. This tutorial covers extension authoring in detail: https://forge-tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/dashboard/basic.

Comment: I added my extension to this package according to your guidance, but my control panel doesn't work and connects to my model.

Comment: there are these Errors. 

Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: viewer is not defined
    at RobotExtension.setTransformation (RobotExt.js:69:9)
    at RobotExtension.load (RobotExt.js:35:14)
    at extension.<computed> [as load] (viewer3D.js:10975:27)
    at GuiViewer3D.loadExtensionLocal (viewer3D.js:11427:34)

Comment: at GuiViewer3D.loadExtension (viewer3D.js:11286:19)
    at GuiViewer3D.<anonymous> (index.js:171:12)
    at GuiViewer3D.dispatchEvent (viewer3D.js:9982:35)
    at Viewer3DImpl.onLoadComplete (viewer3D.js:27687:14)
    at SvfLoader.onGeomLoadDone (viewer3D.js:46586:21)
    at onMeshLoad (viewer3D.js:46105:17)

Comment: Hi Mojgan, it sounds like your extension code is trying to access a `viewer` variable which has not been defined. If that code is inside your extension, consider replacing it with `this.viewer` because each extension includes a reference to the viewer.

Comment: Hi Petr Broz, 
If you mean this, ((this. viewer = viewer;)) ? I had it in my extension code file.
Also, I had these:
((customize() {
        this.defaultState = this.viewer.getState();
        this.viewer.restoreState(someViewerState);
        this.viewer.impl.setPostProcessParameter("style", "edging");
        this.viewer.impl.setPostProcessParameter("depthEdges", false);
        this.viewer.setBackgroundColor(255,255,255,255,255,255);
        this.viewer.setGroundShadow(false);
        this.viewer.setGroundReflection(true);
        this.viewer.setTheme("light-theme");

Comment: But unfortunately, it doesn't work and my control panel does not connect to my model. What would you recommend to me to fix this issue?

Comment: Please edit the original question and add the source code of the extension that you're trying to add to the forge-iot-extensions-demo sample. We can take it from there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, sure. 
Sorry, just I didn't get it, where should I put my question and source code? 
on Stackflow or Github (forge-IoT-extensions-demo sample)?

Comment: You should be able to edit your original question here on Stack Overflow. Just add the code of your extension at the end of the question.

Comment: Please check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/74711811/14428971

Comment: because there is limitation character for upload code file, I had to delete some part of my code and add pictures to my question,  you can find place of pictures on code. 
my code works with pictures of my code that I deleted.