# Extension Autodesk Forge: My IFC 4 model can not connect to my extension

Tags: autodesk-forge, vscode-extensions, controlpanel

I uploaded my IFC version 4 to Autodesk forge and then added my extension, unfortunately, my control panel can not work and connect to my model.
Also, I had this problem with the Revit model but solved it with a solution from Mr. Petr Broz.

Please check this ([Extension Autodesk Forge: My control panel doesn't connect to the Revit model after adding my own extension to the package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74711811/extension-autodesk-forge-my-control-panel-doesnt-connect-to-the-model-after-ad/74713282#74713282)).

unfortunately, the solution for the Revit model doesn't work for the IFC4 model.
Would you please Guide me on how I can solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see the full extension code from the thread you pointed out, but this problem should not be related to IFC4.

From your code snippet, I can see that there is a great possibility that the`setTransformation` function would be called before the geometries are loaded completely. Before completely loaded geometries, fragment info like transform matrix, bounding box, and so on would not be completed. Therefore, I would advise you to `setTransformation` function after `Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT` is triggered to avoid this problem.

```js
if(model.isLoadDone() ) {
    viewer.addEventListner(
      `Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT`,
      () => {
           this.setTransformation();
      }, { once: true }); //!<<< run this even handler once
} else {
  this.setTransformation();
}
```

Or call the async function `viewer.waitForLoadDone()` before calling `setTransformation` function to ensure geometries are loaded completely.

```js
await viewer.waitForLoadDone();
this.setTransformation();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
Unfortunately, both solutions did not work. still, I have a problem with this. my most errors on viewer 3D, why? Please check my error picture.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce this issue with my IFC model, so if you could consider providing a non-confidential test case containing a minimum completed yet runnable viewer code and reproducible steps on how to reproduce this issue to `aps (DOT) help (AT) autodesk (DOT) com`, I'm happy to help. Otherwise, I'm sorry that we are not able to help with limited information. We appreciate your understanding and cooperation.